# How to create as scatter plot with regression line based on statsmodel OLS?

Tags: python, linear-regression, seaborn, statsmodels

I am having difficulty adding a regression line (the one which statsmodel OLS is based on) on to scatter plot.  Note that with seaborn's lmplot, I can get a line (see example), but I would like to use the exact one coming from statsmodel OLS for total consistency.

How can I adjust code below to add in the regression line into the first scatter plot?

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

data = {'Xvalue': range(20, 30), 'Yvalue': np.random.randint(low=10, high=100, size=10)}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

X = data[['Xvalue']]
Y = data['Yvalue']
model2 = sm.OLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X), data=data)
model_fit = model2.fit()
print(model_fit.summary())

#Plot
data.plot(kind='scatter', x='Xvalue', y='Yvalue')

#Seaborn
sns.lmplot(x='Xvalue', y='Yvalue', data=data)
```

**Scatter plot (trying to work out how to add in the statsmodel OLS regression line**

[image: Scatter plot (trying to work out how to add in the statsmodel OLS regression line]

**seaborn lmplot with its regression line (trying to mimic this)**

[image: seaborn lmplot with its regression line (trying to mimic this)]

Comment: What's the problem or error? Do you just not know how to plot the results from statsmodels?

Comment: Correct, I just want the line to come through, to match the line to come through as well (to match the summary() results)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261976/how-to-plot-statsmodels-linear-regression-ols-cleanly (which should help you)

Comment: Thanks it works!

Comment: Btw - how would I adjust the seaborn one to extend the x-axis to go all the way to 0 as well?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link from @busybear, it now works!

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

data = {'Xvalue': range(20, 30), 'Yvalue': np.random.randint(low=10, high=100, size=10)}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

X = data[['Xvalue']]
Y = data['Yvalue']
model = sm.OLS(data['Yvalue'], sm.add_constant(data['Xvalue']))
model_fit = model.fit()
p = model_fit.params
print(model_fit.summary())


#Plot
p
x = np.arange(0,40)
ax = data.plot(kind='scatter', x='Xvalue', y='Yvalue')
ax.plot(x, p.const + p.Xvalue * x)
ax.set_xlim([0,30])

#Seaborn
sns.lmplot(x='Xvalue', y='Yvalue', data=data)
```

[image]