# How to plot regression results using statsmodels with single categorical (3 levels) independent variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics, statsmodels

I have a numerical dependent varible *Y* and one categorical independent variable *X* with 3 levels (x1, x2 and x3).

*Y* corresponds to the measurement of a sensor and *X* to three measurement conditions. Let's say I measured luminance of (*Y*) under 3 different conditions (*X*: x1, x2 and x3).

I'm using the statsmodels python library to perform a regression (how measurement conditions affect luminance)

```
res = smf.ols(formula='Y ~ C(X)', data=df_cont).fit()
```

Now I need to plot the regression results (linear fit) and the "raw" data on the same plot. The plot I have in mind is something like this mock example:

[[image: example1]

I've tried the statsmodels `plot_fit` and `albine_plot` but have not managed to make it work. I've tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261976/how-to-plot-statsmodels-linear-regression-ols-cleanly) but I'm still not able to do it.

Any idea on how to accomplish this would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fit a linear model like you did, you are estimating a mean for every category, it is a not a slope and intercept fit through all your data points,for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':np.random.normal(np.repeat([0,1.5,2.5],20),1,60),
                  'X':np.repeat(['x1','x2','x3'],20)})

df['X'] = pd.Categorical(df['X'],categories=['x1','x2','x3'])

res = smf.ols(formula= "Y ~ X",data=df).fit()
res.summary()

    coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
Intercept   -0.0418 0.233   -0.180  0.858   -0.508  0.424
X[T.x2] 1.3507  0.329   4.102   0.000   0.691   2.010
X[T.x3] 2.5947  0.329   7.880   0.000   1.935   3.254
```

To plot these results, you can do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x = "X",y = "Y",ax=ax)
ncat = len(res.params)
ax.scatter(x = np.arange(ncat)+0.1,y = res.params , color = "#FE9898")
ax.vlines(x = np.arange(ncat)+0.1,
          ymin = res.conf_int().iloc[:,0],
          ymax = res.conf_int().iloc[:,1],
         color = "#FE9898")
```

[image]

If you really have to force a line, bear in mind this does not come from the regression you've just shown:

```
sns.regplot(x = df['X'].cat.codes,y = df['Y'],ax=ax,scatter=False,color="#628395")
fig
```

[image]